# Service endpoint not receiving published events

Tags: rebus

I've finally gotten around to deploy my solution to our dev environment and I am running into an issue where my endpoint is not receiving published events. this does indeed work on my local machine but not when messages are chatting between remote servers.

**edit**
i'm also running the windows service as the network service and rebus logging is working fine.

Here is my configuration setup:

**Publisher**

```
Configure.With(new SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter(container))
                .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("Identity.Web"))
                .Subscriptions(s => s.StoreInSqlServer("Integration", "Subscription", true, true))
                .Options(b => b.EnableMessageAuditing("Identity.Web.Audit"))
                .Options(b => b.SimpleRetryStrategy(errorQueueAddress: "Identity.Web.Error"))
                .Start();
```

**Endpoint Receiver**

```
var bus = Configure.With(new CastleWindsorContainerAdapter(container))
                .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("Comply360.User.Management"))
                .Subscriptions(s => s.StoreInSqlServer("Integration", "Subscription", isCentralized: true))
                .Options(b => b.EnableMessageAuditing("Comply360.User.Management.Audit"))
                .Options(b => b.SimpleRetryStrategy(errorQueueAddress: "Comply360.User.Management.Error"))
                .Logging(l => l.Serilog(Log.Logger))
                .Start();

            bus.Subscribe<UserCreated>();
            bus.Subscribe<UserUpdated>();
```

Here is the publishing code:

```
await this.bus.Publish(new Events.UserUpdated
    {
        UserId = notification.Id,
        Firstname = notification.Firstname,
        Lastname = notification.Lastname,
    });
```

And the two records in my subscription store:

```
Identity.Events.UserCreated, Identity.Messages  Comply360.User.Management@MACHINE
Identity.Events.UserUpdated, Identity.Messages  Comply360.User.Management@MACHINE
```

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you're calling `bus.Subscribe<TEvent>()` without awaiting the result. You should always either

```
await bus.Subscribe<TEvent>();
```

if you're in an `async` method, or

```
bus.Subscribe<TEvent>().Wait();
```

if you aren't.

However I don't that that is the cause of your problem.

I can see that you correctly `await` when you publish - that's good :)

I suspect that it is an issue with MSMQ and queue rights. Could you try and go to Computer Management and take a look at the transactional dead-letter queue on the publisher machine?

[image: tx dead-letters]

If messages were sent, but they did not reach the recipient because of some issue (network issues, user rights issues, + many more), they will end up in the transactional dead-letter queue.

Comment: please see edit. i also checked the msmq End2End log on the endpoing and it says "Message came over network"

Comment: im not at my machine to check but i read windows 2008 does not open up permissions for anomymous login or everyone groups. do u know what all permissions are required for senders? send, peek, etc?

Comment: I have usually installed my Windows Services to be logged on as a domain account service user. When machines are on the same domain, configuring the rights on individual queues is pretty easy - just right click, go to properties/security, and assign appropriate rights

Comment: i think the problem is my sender is coming from a website that runs under IIS APPPOOL\XXX so I need to configure the ANONYMOUS LOGON on the receiving msmq. i'm assuming you are not using Windows 2008 because from what I have read you have to set this manually. Do you know what permissions the sender needs? Can you look at your private queue permissions?

Comment: You could probably configure it so that "Everyone" has "Full control" or something. But the best solution would definitely be if you configured your apppool to run under a service account. That would also make it easier to configure e.g. database access, access to local directories, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Came across same problem during my work on functionapp and EventHub.
Number of pre-warned instances of FunctionApp should be equal/grater than EventHub partition count. Once changing this configuration I was about to get all events perfectly.